# node-sass error when installing on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, npm

I'm having problems installing node-sass on my server.

```
root@west:/usr/lib/node_modules# npm install -g node-sass
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
/usr/bin/node-sass -> /usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass

> node-sass@4.13.1 install /usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Unable to save binary /usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-79 : Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:887:3)
    at sync (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:72:13)
    at Function.sync (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:78:24)
    at checkAndDownloadBinary (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:114:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:157:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
}

> node-sass@4.13.1 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@13.11.0 | linux | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.17
gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 13.11.0
gyp verb command install [ '13.11.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "13.11.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 13.11.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/13.11.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp"
gyp verb tmpdir == cwd automatically will remove dev files after to save disk space
gyp verb command install [ '--node_gyp_internal_noretry', '13.11.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "13.11.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 13.11.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 13.11.0
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/13.11.0
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp verb command remove [ '13.11.0' ]
gyp verb remove using node-gyp dir: /usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp
gyp verb remove removing target version: 13.11.0
gyp verb remove removing development files for version: 13.11.0
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp verb command remove [ '13.11.0' ]
gyp verb remove using node-gyp dir: /usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp
gyp verb remove removing target version: 13.11.0
gyp verb remove removing development files for version: 13.11.0
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-88-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v13.11.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-26T08_39_09_785Z-debug.log
```

The issue seems to be around permissions:

> gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir
>   '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp'

Yet it seems ok here:

```
root@west:/usr/lib/node_modules# ls -lh
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K Mar 25 20:18 @babel
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4.0K Mar 25 20:17 npm
```

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:** I've even tried using NVM to configure the node version:

```
curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh
bash install_nvm.sh
source ~/.profile
nvm install 12.16.1
nvm use 12.16.1
```

But I still get errors:

```
sudo npm install -g node-sass
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
/root/.npm-global/bin/node-sass -> /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass

> node-sass@4.13.1 install /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:859:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.13.1 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.13.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-26T10_10_11_044Z-debug.log
```

**UPDATE 2:**

So I have managed to install  it with:

```
sudo npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

> node-sass@4.13.1 install /root/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at /root/.npm/node-sass/4.13.1/linux-x64-79_binding.node

> node-sass@4.13.1 postinstall /root/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /root/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-79/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/package.json'
npm WARN root No description
npm WARN root No repository field.
npm WARN root No README data
npm WARN root No license field.

+ node-sass@4.13.1
added 172 packages from 137 contributors and audited 528 packages in 7.275s

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

However, how do I now access it? I've tried:

```
sass --help
node-sass --help
```

Neither seem to work. "whereis" comes back with:

```
whereis node-sass
node-sass: /usr/bin/node-sass
```